# Turn Vim's multiple undo history into git commits?

Tags: git, undo-redo

When refactoring I sometimes do too much at once—all little steps, but I forget to commit after each little change.

Of course in many cases a commit after *each* change would be too much, but if each individual change were initially made as a separate commit, it would be very easy to `git rebase` them to combine them into logical, atomic changes.

Is there a way to convert each point in Vim's multiple undo history into a separate git commit?

Comment: Why don't use `git add -p`? Using this command someone can selectively stage modifications; edit, split into smaller hunks and commit them.

Comment: @dNitro, good answer for most people, but I'm already familiar with that.  It's not quite so useful when you end up modifying every line of the file so the whole thing is considered as one "hunk."  Of course you can remove lines by editing the hunk manually, but then there are the cases when you change a line and then change the same line *again.*

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick and dirty function that does what you request:

```
function! UndoCommits(steps)
    for i in range(a:steps)
        undo
    endfor

    for i in range(a:steps)
        write
        execute printf('!silent git commit -am "%s"', "undo-commit" . i)
        redo
    endfor
    write
    execute printf('!silent git commit -am "%s"', "final-undo-commit")
    redraw!
endfunction
```

Call with `:call UndoCommits({N})` where {N} is the number of undo steps back you want to go.

The function simply undoes the requested number of times, and then redoes the changes one at a time, making a commit between each change.

Personally, I think I'd just do this manually — I guess a compromise might be to create a mapping that just performs the save-and-commit, and then run this mapping by hand at the relevant parts of the undolist.

Comment: `UndoCommits` doesn't incorporate branches in the undo history, though.

Comment: Is there a way to time-stamp each commit with the date/time of the undo? ([Gundo](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim) get the time of each undo somewhere; I'm not sure where in its source code.)

Comment: @Geremia Continuing with the "quick-n-dirty" theme, you could get it to include all entries from the undo tree by using [`:earlier`](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html#%3Aea) and `:later` instead of `:undo` and `:redo`. If you want to include the time information, you're going to need to implement something a bit more complicated that cross-references the return value of [`undotree()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#undotree%28%29), which contains this information.

Comment: @Geremia I rejected your edit because it didn't preserve the original answer. Please post an answer of your own with you solution this way future readers can see the different options and choose the one they prefer.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend one of the *undo tree visualizer plugins*:

- [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree)
- [Gundo](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/)

With them, you can easily revisit previous editing states. You can them (temporarily) restore them (one by one, starting with the oldest relevant), and `git commit` them, until you arrive back at the original.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon [Rich's solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9727/5224), this one timestamps each commit:

```
function! UndoCommits()
    let steps = undotree()['seq_last']
    for i in range(steps)
        earlier
    endfor
    for i in range(steps)
    write
        execute printf('!git commit -am "%s" --date=%d &>/dev/null', "undo-commit" . i, undotree()['time_cur'])
        later
    endfor
    write
    execute printf('!git commit -am "final-undo-commit" --date=%d &>/dev/null', undotree()['time_cur'])
    redraw!
endfunction
```

Usage: `:call UndoCommits()`. It will make git commits starting from the current position in the undo tree all the way back to the oldest revision.

Comment: Oh hey that didn’t turn out to be that much more complicated at all. Good job!

Comment: This only does a single branch of the tree though, right? To get the entire graph would be harder

Comment: @D.BenKnoble It makes Git commits with the whole undo tree from the current position in the tree. It does not make new Git branches to reflect undo tree branches.

Comment: Agreed about git branches; what I’m looking at is that either it process the whole tree in some kind of linearized fashion, or it only process the linear history between start and now. So either way some information is lost, compared to plugins that show the entire undotree in a tree

Comment: @D.BenKnoble "_either way some information is lost_" No undo tree revisions (on only undo tree branch) between the current one and the file's first one are lost. "_either it process the whole tree in some kind of linearized fashion, or it only process the linear history between start and now_" What's the difference?

Comment: Consider this sequence: 1. Change line to A. 2. Undo. 3. Change line to B. Now, the undo tree has at least three nodes: the initial node, one from that to the change A, and one from the initial node to the change B (also the current the node). Linearized history would mean you write commits initial node <- A <- B. Only processing the current linear history would mean you write commits initial node <- B. In the first, we've lost the fact that A and B are in separate branches of the undo tree. In the second, we've lost A altogether.

Comment: I _believe_ `undotree()` represents its branching via `alt` fields in the entries.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble "_In the second, we've lost A altogether._" When using `undo` and `redo`, but not when using `earlier` and `later`. See [Rich's comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9715/turn-vims-multiple-undo-history-into-git-commits/37183?noredirect=1#comment67697_9727) above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135418/discussion-between-d-ben-knoble-and-geremia).