# visualize Vim undo history

Tags: git, undo-redo, version-control-systems

Is there for Vim what [Gource](https://gource.io/) is for Git, to visualize Vim undo history?

I'm familiar with [Gundo](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim), which display diffs of undo history, but it's not really a visualizer like [Gource](https://gource.io/) for Git repos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the undo history into a Git repo using [Rich's `UndoCommits` function](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9727/5224), then use something like `gitk` to visualize that Git repo's diffs.

[Gource](https://gource.io/) would only be useful if each commit `UnoCommits` produces were timestamped with the date/time of the undo; I'm not sure how to get that info, but it must be in the [Gundo](https://github.com/sjl/gundo.vim) source code somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: this is only an alternative, not a relevant answer.

You're looking for [vim undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree).

It shows the full history tree, and diffs with the current version.

Comment: Another one is [vim-mundo](https://github.com/simnalamburt/vim-mundo).

Comment: Those are basically the same as Gundo.

Comment: @Geremia indeed, sorry about that.